# Are unicode characters / emojis acceptable as passwords for mobile phones?

Tags: unicode, passwords, emoji, password-encryption

If we create a mobile web app, it might be convenient for users to use an emoji/unicode character in their passwords. Is this a bad idea, would it work?

Comment: In of itself, it is fine, if you accept user input as Unicode to begin with, and transmit it from the app to the web server in a way that does not lose the characters.  The real question is, what are you doing with the passwords after they have been entered into the app, and does that something support Unicode emojis as input, transmission, and hashing/storage?

Answer (score 1):

The article http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/02/unicode-versus-passwords-versus-digests.html goes a bit into the details. The big problem is that text in Unicode can be expressed by multiple equivalent representations (I'm not talking about encoding here). Unfortunately you are prevented from using the simple and correct solution of text matching using UTS #10 §§3.5, 11 where the differences don't matter; security best practice prescribes that you don't store the password, but only a digest of it, so a normalisation step before hashing is crucial.

IMO it's not necessarily a bad idea, just work-intensive.